# Kong Ingress Controller with CORS plugin failed with preflight connect

Tags: cors, kong-ingress

I use the CORS plugin with Kong ingress controller, whitin Postman, the API works great, the response includes an

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
```

header.

But when I made cors request in Chrome, it report:

```
Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

Edge report:

```
The server has not found anything matching the requested URI (Uniform Resource Identifier).
```

My upstream service is a express/node app, I already set the cors middleware, but it seems the preflight HTTP OPTIONS request won't go through or get response from the Kong gateway.

And I noticed the plugin has an [limitation](https://docs.konghq.com/hub/kong-inc/cors/#cors-limitations).

But I don't know to configure my KongIngress object to overcome this limitation in broswer for cors request.

Comment: Changed to gloo :sad

Comment: Is the necessary header actually included in the request? Your express/node app could be limiting the size of headers, as it's default is kinda small. You can try passing `--max-http-header-size=100000` or something like that to .node options and verify the headers is actually present when reaching the ingress